# How to sync a patched or rebased GIT repository?

Tags: git, github, rebase

The owner of a repo that I forked regularly rebases and patches his commits (and push requests) rather than just merging or adding them. When I want to sync with his repo, git/Github wants to merge everything since the patched commit, although only this patch should be synced.

Ok I think I must specify my problem. Yes, its no problem to PULL the changes from upstream into my local repo, because I can rebase here as well. But when I want to sync my fork on GitHub (origin), I dont know how to rebase the commit history there as well. When I want to push my rebased history, git tells me that I have to pull from origin first, because the base has changed (becaus I rebased my local copy of my Github fork).

So the question is more likely, how to sync my Github fork with the original rebased repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can't rebase 2 repositories: **your forked repository** vs. **upstream repository**. You only apply `merge`.

Reference about update a fork: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Answer (score 1):

If the owner has rewritten commits using rebase och ammend I would say that you have to use cherry-pick or interactive rebase.

**Cherry pick**

1. Checkout the new branch you want to sync to
2. Cherry pick each of your own commits

**Interactive rebase**

1. Start an interactive rebase
2. Set all commits to which you're not the author to skip

**Edit, updated question**

To be able to push your local branch to your own repo you have to use `--force` to overwrite the old commits that have changed. Like so

```
git push origin master:master --force
```

After a rebase or an amend the changed commits will be completely different (the commit time will change even if you don't change any content and with that you get a completely new commit hash). You therefore need to "throw away" the old commits that are in you github repo.

Comment: I updated my question, its more about my github fork

Comment: Updated answer to include your clarifications